# UICollectionView scrolling a specific length

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with a single row. I want scrolling to work such that after the scroll, the new cell places itself at the same position as the previous one, something like paging does for a whole page.

Answer (score 0):

If your `UICollectionViewCell` is taking up the whole screen, you can use: 
`[self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];` 
This will automatically allow you to achieve the effect I understand you are looking for.

Comment: I have like 3 cells in a screen. So if I use pagingEnabled, it will skip 3 cells... :(